# patchValue just does not work! What does?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue with my image upload feature. On one of the component forms there are 8 entries, 7 text entries and 1 image upload entry. The form submits to my node server fine and all data is present, however the image upload feature only works sometimes.

If I try to select an image first I get the error "Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."

```
<button class="btn logo" mat-stroked-button type="button"
   (click)="filePicker.click()">Pick Image
</button>
<input type="file" #filePicker formControlName="logo"
   name="logo" (change)="onImagePicked($event)" />
```

I understand that but every example I have seen has the same or similar syntax. Is there more than one way to do this?

If I change the data in 3 of the fields first and then select an image the feature works as expected by uploading the file to multer, adding the filename to the db, and returning the results but I still get the failed to set value error even though it works???? I don't get it. It works but it doesn't.

```
this.adminSettingsForm.patchValue({'logo': file,}); // doesn't work

this.adminSettingsForm.patchValue({['logo']: file,}); // doesn't work

this.adminSettingsForm.patchValue({[logo]: file,}); // doesn't work

this.adminSettingsForm.controls['logo'].patchValue(file, {emitEvent : false}); // doesn't work

this.adminSettingsForm.get('logo').updateValueAndValidity(); // throws an error because of the above.
```

This is my service that is sending and receiving the right data... all except the image.

```
updateStoreInfo(
storeName: string, logo: File, address: string,
city: string, state: string, zip: string, phone: string, email: string
) {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('storeName', storeName);
formData.append('logo', logo);
formData.append('address', address);
formData.append('city', city);
formData.append('state', state);
formData.append('zip', zip);
formData.append('phone', phone);
formData.append('email', email);

return this.http.post<{ message: string; settings: Settings }>(`${this.serverUrl}/admin/settings/storeInfo`, formData)
  .subscribe(result => {
    const resData = result;
    alert(resData['message']);
    const adminSettings = resData['settings'];
this.settingsChanged(adminSettings);
  });
```

}

And here is my node server function

```
router.post('/settings/storeInfo', multer({dest: imgDir, storage: 
imgStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter})
  .fields([
    { name: 'logo', maxCount: 1 },
  ]), (req, res, next) => {


  storeSettingsId = req.body.storeSettingsId
  StoreSettings.findById(storeSettingsId)
    .then(settings => {
      if (req.files.logo) {
        settings.image= req.files.logo[0].filename;
      } else {
        settings.image = settings.image;
      }

      settings.storeName = req.body.storeName,
      settings.address = req.body.address,
      settings.city = req.body.city,
      settings.state = req.body.state,
      settings.zip = req.body.zip,
      settings.phone = req.body.phone,
      settings.email = req.body.email,
      settings.save();

      return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Settings Saved!', settings });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });

  });
```

I have 6 more forms like this one each with different numbers of image uploads. From 1 image to 20. When I submit a form with more than one image the last image is ignored. I've been trying to figure this out for over a week and I think I'm stuck. I can't figure it out and I'm out of liquor! Someone please give me a solution that I haven't googled already that works.

UPDATE: 
I have updated my code above and have rebuilt my form and have tried the following lines:
    this.adminSettingsForm.patchValue({ 'logo': file });
    // doesn't work - Failed to set the 'value' property... (console)

```
   this.adminSettingsForm.patchValue({'logo': file, });
// doesn't work with trailing comma - Failed to set the 'value' property... (console)

   this.adminSettingsForm.patchValue({['logo']: file, });
// doesn't work - Failed to set the 'value' property... (console)

   this.adminSettingsForm.patchValue({[logo]: file, });
// doesn't work - did I mean this.logo(IDE) - logo not defined(console)

   this.adminSettingsForm.controls['logo'].patchValue(file);
// refErr 'logo is not defined'

   this.adminSettingsForm.controls['logo'].patchValue(file, {emitEvent : false});
// dooesn't work - Failed to set the 'value' property... (console)

   this.adminSettingsForm.controls['logo'].value = file;
// Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a read-only property. Breaks build but not error in console

   this.adminSettingsForm.value['logo'].value = file; // doesn't work
```

Every part of this feature works except updating the file value entered. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening. I'm at a complete loss and I keep coding in circles.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.adminSettingsForm.controls['image'].value = file;
```

or

```
this.adminSettingsForm.value['image'].value = file;
```

Comment: Thanks b ut your first example throws an error in my IDE and stops my build -  error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a constant or a read-only property.o 'value' because it is a constant or a read-only property..

Your second example gives an error in my console - Cannot create property 'value' on string 'C:\fakepath\...

Comment: For anyone else having the same problem I finally figured out it was that I had a formControlName on my input.